# How can I use a single-shot timer to implement an repeating timer?

Tags: timer

In some easy system, it only offer the single-shot timer APIs. But I want an repeating timer. How can I achieve it? Please give an example, thank you so much.

Especially，the callback function of single-shot timer is defined like

```
void OnTimer(void);
```

When I want to use a lot timer and try to manage them, I find this problem.

Comment: Set another single-shot timer each time one of them triggers.

Comment: @Bibhas but I want to manage more than 20 timers, and the callback function without bring the TIMER ID. It is not easy.

Comment: `In some easy system` is not really a problem description. Be more specific. What exactly your problem? Don't comment, update your question with more details.